# How to make Windows START command accept standard input via pipe and pass it on to the command it invokes?

Tags: windows, batch-file, pipeline

See this script saved in a file called `foo.cmd`.

```
@echo off
more +5
```

This script may now be used in this manner.

```
dir C:\Windows | foo
```

It displays the output beginning from the 6th line, one screen at a time (i.e. as a pager). The current command prompt remains blocked until I quit `more`.

Now I modify the script as follows, so that the more output is displayed in a separate window.

```
@echo off
start "" more +5
```

Now if I run the following command, a new window is launched fine, but no output is displayed in it.

```
dir C:\Windows | foo
```

It appears that the output of the `dir` command that I have piped into `foo.cmd` is not being received by the `start` command.

What can I do to ensure that any data piped into the standard input of the `start` command is passed on to the program being invoked by `start` (which is `more` in this case)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to pipe into another window. Your START command within your parent window is receiving the pipe input. The START command ignores the input. You want the MORE command in the new window to receive the input.

I believe the only way to achieve your goal is to use a temporary file:

```
@echo off
set "file=%temp%\%~nx0.temp"
findstr "^" >"%file%"
start "" cmd /c more +5 ^<"%file%" ^& del "%file%" ^& pause
```

Comment: Why do you use ^< before "%file%"?

Comment: He's using `findstr` as a `cat` command, which Windows lacks. `findstr` applies a regular expression to its input lines and writes those lines that match to its output. `^` matches the beginning of a line, so all lines get copied, like cat.

Answer (score 1):

There is another way: you can run the pipe *inside* the `start` command.

For the example above, you would keep `foo.bat` in its original version:

```
@echo off
more +5
```

and invoke it like this:

```
start dir C:\Windows ^| foo.bat
```

*This tells `start` to run the `dir` command. As `dir` is recognized to be an internal command, `start` will actually run `cmd /c` and pass it the remaining arguments. This in turn will allow the pipe to be created inside the command spawned by `start` (and also why the pipe is escaped).*

*(Side note - no `""` is needed here as a first parameter to `start`, because the `dir` argument isn't quoted - that's a quirk of the `start` command.)*

If you want to make this an elegant command so you don't need to run start every time, you can instead pass the directory to your script, and do all the magic inside:

```
foo.bat C:\Windows
```

and foo.bat becomes:

```
@echo off
start dir %1 ^| more +5
```

(Of course, this is at the cost of only being able to run `dir` in your script instead of it being a generic pager.)

Lastly, if you are running something other than `dir`, you may have to run `cmd` explicitly:

```
start cmd /c some_command ^| foo.bat
```